# Exchange 2013 Mail flow rule using RegEx

Tags: regex, email, exchange-server, rule

We're trying to implement a rule on certain mailboxes that it shouldn't accept an email without a subject.

I found documentation from Microsoft on exchange 2010 to [Configure a Transport Rule for Messages That Have a Blank Subject](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb430785%28v=exchg.141%29.aspx), but I tried using the `^$` RegEx with Exchange 2013 and it doesn't seem to work.

I also looked at the [Transport Rule Predicates](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj919235%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) for Exchange 2013 and it clearly says that `SubjectMatchesPatterns matches messages where text patterns in the Subject field match a specified regular expression`.

My workaround was to reject all messages to those specific mailboxes except if subject pattern matches `.` but if I want to add now conditions ie. to reject emails with a subject "Sent from my snipping tool" I can't do it.

I found [Here](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/jj150483%28v=exchg.150%29.aspx) that Exchange 2013 now supports extended RegEx but I didn't find that the syntax for `^$` should be any different in extended RegEx.

Comment: Just so you know, serverfault.com also has a lot of Exchange experts.  It's a sister site to this one.

Answer (score 0):

`\s+` matches whitespace, maybe try that.

Comment: I appreciate your attempt to help but it's still not working with exchange.